# Sharepoint 2010 documents can not be saved

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-office

I am having an issue with my Sharepoint documents library.  Users are unable to update the documents.  Whenever the checkout a document to edit (be it excel or word doc) an error message appears at the top of the document:

To save to the server, correct the invalid or missing required properties.

All the required properties are filled in but I have one required property that is of external data type. When I make that property not required, the error message disappears and I am able to save the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might help you!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928037